# How should we deal with the growing Repository in a mvp project's model layer?

Tags: android, repository-pattern, mvp

Google has launched a project on Github in order to demonstrate different architecture implementations.

[todo-mvp](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp/)

In its' simple MVP implementation's model layer, which applies the Repository pattern, it simply contains one POJO(Task) and we already have a bloated model layer here.

[image]

It's quite common to have dozens of POJOs in a **REAL** project. And it's easy to imagine how big the repository would grow.

Whenever I want to add or amend something, like adding a Owner(of a Task), I have to add so many lines of code in each one of the classes in the model layer. No need to mention that we have to write so many hard-coded SQL statements.

Is there a better way to avoid these things?

Comment: I have a similar issue . On the other hand, if I want to load more data . How should I define it in Repository .

Answer (score 0):

That project structure is good. If you want to save your time and avoid writing many lines of boring SQL statements, you can adopt some ORM libraries such as Realm, GreenORM etc. Same for the other stuffs.

Also checkout a new MVP framework here: http://robo-creative.github.io/mvp. With it, you can avoid writing tangled logic for view-presenter binding. The framework also supports Dependency Injection as well.